# how to group by, and select from two tables, need two records for each given id

Tags: sql, group-by

I am new to SQL query.
Can you please help me with the following?

#### table 1 QuoteObservations:

```
id value quotePointId asOfTime
```

#### table 2   QuotePoints:

```
id, quotoType
```

quoteType could be LastPrice, RepoRate, etc

I need to select id and value, asOfTime, quoteType, with highest asOfTime from table 1 with quoteType=LastPrice ( =1) or RepoRate (=2) in table 2; I need to return two records, one for last price, one for repo rate for each id, but both last price and repo rate should be with the highest asOfTime.

I have this, but it gives either last price or repo rate whichever has the higher asOfTime.

```
SELECT QuoteObservations.id, QuoteObservations.value, 
QuoteObservations.quotePointId, max(QuoteObservations.asOfTime) as asOfTime, 
QuoteObservations.dataProviderId, QuotePoints.quoteType 
FROM QuoteObservations, QuotePoints 
WHERE (QuoteObservations.id =1 OR QuoteObservations.id = 2 ) 
AND QuoteObservations.quotePointId = QuotePoints.id 
AND (QuotePoints.quoteType = 1 or QuotePoints.quoteType = 2)
group by QuoteObservations.id, QuoteObservations.value, 
QuoteObservations.quotePointId,QuoteObservations.dataProviderId, QuotePoints.quoteType;
```

Comment: The term "not working" is vague.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the WHERE condition that is limiting the results on `QuoteObservations.id =1 OR QuoteObservations.id = 2`

Here is the revised SQL, with that condition removed. I have also moved the JOIN conditon into the JOIN clause.

```
SELECT  QuoteObservations.id, 
        QuoteObservations.value, 
        QuoteObservations.quotePointId,
        max(QuoteObservations.asOfTime) as asOfTime, 
        QuoteObservations.dataProviderId,
        QuotePoints.quoteType 
FROM    QuoteObservations
INNER JOIN
        QuotePoints 
ON      QuoteObservations.quotePointId = QuotePoints.id 
WHERE   QuotePoints.quoteType in (1,2)
group by 
        QuoteObservations.id, 
        QuoteObservations.value, 
        QuoteObservations.quotePointId,
        QuoteObservations.dataProviderId, 
        QuotePoints.quoteType;
```

Comment: but I meant that
for 1 id, I need two quotes, one last price, one repo_rate, both should be the most recent (with highest asOfTime)

Comment: Do I need to query twice, one for quoteType = 1 and one for quotype = 2 to get the last price and repo Rate with highest timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    QuoteObservations.id, 
    QuoteObservations.value, 
    QuoteObservations.asOfTime,
    QuotePoints.quoteType
FROM
    QuoteObservations
    LEFT JOIN QuotePoints
    ON QuoteObservations.quotePointId = QuotePoints.id
WHERE
    QuotePoints.quoteType = 1 
    OR QuotePoints.quoteType = 2
ORDER BY 
    QuoteObservations.asOfTime DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I craeted this query, it works, but I bet there is a better and more efficient way to do it, can anyone out  there help?

```
select q.*
from (
            select     QuoteObservations.id, QuoteObservations.value,   QuoteObservations.quotePointId, max(QuoteObservations.asOfTime) as asOfTime, QuoteObservations.dataProviderId, qp.quoteType
            from [QuoteObservations]
            inner join QuotePoints qp
            on qp.id = QuoteObservations.quotePointId
            where quotePointId = 1
            group by QuoteObservations.id, QuoteObservations.value, QuoteObservations.quotePointId, QuoteObservations.dataProviderId
    ) q
inner join (

            select     QuoteObservations.id, QuoteObservations.value, QuoteObservations.quotePointId, max(QuoteObservations.asOfTime) as asOfTime, QuoteObservations.dataProviderId, qp.quoteType
            from [QuoteObservations]
            inner join QuotePoints qp
            on qp.id = QuoteObservations.quotePointId
            where quotePointId = 2
            group by QuoteObservations.id, QuoteObservations.value, QuoteObservations.quotePointId, QuoteObservations.dataProviderId
) p
    on  q.id = p.id
inner join (
            select     QuoteObservations.id, QuoteObservations.value, QuoteObservations.quotePointId, max(QuoteObservations.asOfTime) as asOfTime, QuoteObservations.dataProviderId, qp.quoteType
            from [QuoteObservations]
            inner join QuotePoints qp
            on qp.id = QuoteObservations.quotePointId
            where quotePointId = 10
            group by QuoteObservations.id, QuoteObservations.value, QuoteObservations.quotePointId, QuoteObservations.dataProviderId
) s
    on  s.id = p.id
```